# How does the center tap terminal work in Knowles Speakers ED series?

Tags: audio, speakers

I would like to understand how the center tap terminal work in miniature speakers. I can see in the [datasheet](http://www.knowles.com/eng/content/download/4788/66554/version/2/file/ED-29689-000.pdf) that a positive going voltage relative to this center tap can lower the output volume but it does not specify by how much?

How can I calculate that?
How is the actual connection between the 3 pads?

Maybe it is just a parallel connection between the positive pad - the center tap terminal and half the speaker resistance. I just want to be sure of this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.knowles.com/eng/content/download/4788/66554/version/2/file/ED-29689-000.pdf

Comment: Without the manufacturer telling you, I think the only way is to measure the coil inductance or resistance at the two points? I'm guessing a *center tap* would likely be centered, so everything would be halved? Just an educated guess.

Comment: Why is it for? To modify the impedance of the speaker?

Comment: I'm guessing yes. Half the coil, half the power? Like using a center tap on a transformer leading to a smaller voltage or current.

Answer (score -1):

"a positive going voltage relative to this center tap can lower the **output volume**".

The datasheet doesn't actually say that. It says that "a positive going voltage... will cause a decrease in pressure at the sound outlet". I think that all it is saying is that when you apply a positive voltage as specified the internal diaphragm / speaker effectively moves inward causing a reduction in pressure at the sound outlet. You need to drive this unit with an audio signal exactly as you would a speaker.

Comment: So, I do not get why is the center tap terminal for. What would cause a decrease in pressure at the sound outlet?

Comment: Op knows they connect an audio signal, but if they use the center tap instead of the two outside taps, how much would it be reduced by.

Comment: @Passerby I was trying to correct the OP's confusion between **output volume** and **pressure at the sound outlet**.